# django / python get image from url and display on site

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

Given a url to an image is there a way in Django/Python to pull this image in and then display it on my site (resized if possible)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to hotlink it print out the html snippet(`<img src="http://example.com/img.png" width="100" height="100" />`).

If you want to store in at your server and resize it on the server-side you might want to look into [ImageMagick](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ImageMagick) or [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) for processing and [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) or [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) for downloading.

Comment: thanks. think i was looking into it to deep trying to open it with Python :)